# How to load my bash script result to a specific location

Tags: bash, google-cloud-storage

How can I load my output generated from my bash script into a gcs location

My bash command is like:

```bash
echo " hello world"
```

I want this output(hello world) to be shown in a location in gcs.

How to write a location command in Bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should follow the [install Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) instructions in order to use the [cp command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) form [gsutil tool](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil) on the machine you're running the script.

> 1. Cloud SDK requires Python; supported versions are Python 3 (preferred, 3.5 to 3.8) and Python 2 (2.7.9 or higher)
> 2. Run one of the following:
>
> - Linux 64-bit archive file from your command-line, run:
>
>   `curl -O https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-362.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz`
> - For the 32-bit archive file, run:
>
>   `curl -O https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-362.0.0-linux-x86.tar.gz`
> - *Depending on your setup, you can choose other [installation methods](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart#installing_the_latest_version)*
>
> 3. Extract the contents of the file to any location on your file system (preferably your Home directory). If you would like to replace an existing installation, remove the existing  `google-cloud-sdk`  directory and extract the archive to the same location.
> 4. Run  [gcloud init](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/init)  to initialize the SDK:
>    `./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init`

After you have installed the Cloud SDK, you should [create a bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil#create) to [upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil#upload_an_object_into_your_bucket)the files that will contain the output generated by your script.

> Use the `gsutil mb` command and a unique name to create a bucket:
>
> `gsutil mb -b on -l us-east1 gs://my-awesome-bucket/`
>
> *This uses a bucket named "my-awesome-bucket". You must choose your own, globally-unique, bucket name.*

Then you can redirect your output to a local file and upload to Google Cloud Storage like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
TIMESTAMP=$(date +'%s')
BUCKET="my-awesome-bucket"
echo "Hello world!" > "logfile.$TIMESTAMP.log"
gsutil cp logfile.$TIMESTAMP.log gs://$BUCKET/logfile.$TIMESTAMP.log
```